# Cross-platform tool for translating and internationalizing Delphi & FreePascal programs

Tags: delphi, internationalization, lazarus, freepascal

I'm writing a program for both Delphi and Lazarus/FreePascal, so I can also reach customers using Linux or Mac OS X.

Is there a cross-platform tool that works in both environments too, so I can add multiple languages? 
I tried [GNU Gettext for Delphi and C++ Builder](http://dxgettext.po.dk/Home), but it does not compile in Lazarus for Mac OS X. 
Is there anything comparable?

Comment: You could specify the problems you run into when using GNU gettext on Mac OS. Somehow I doubt that it is really incompatible... (Although I never tried it out myself ;-)

Comment: @Mef: Maybe he meant something else than the gettext *unit* when writing "but is broken (not compile in Lazarus/OSX)"? But what would that be? Everything else is not strictly needed.

Comment: Yes, what goes wrong should be described more in depth. Maybe he simply didn't install the relevant Fink libs, or has some unit name conflict (specially since FPC also comes with a gettext unit)

Comment: Well, I download gettext, compile and fail. I try to fix some stuff, but after 3 edits the thing start to become harder to get. If is working then I don't know wich version to get, because I try something like 3 or 4 diferents version, none of them work for me AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

No, simply since the only system that FPC uses is gettext. 
Lazarus afaik uses gettext, also on OS X, but obviously the FPC one, not the delphi one.

I suggest you devote some more attention to getting the gettext solution to work, maybe asking specific questions here.

In reply to your comment:

If I look in the LCL, I see in the *translate* routines stuff that translates properties of tpersistents, but only for special "TTranslatestrings" fields. So it doesn't seem to translate full forms directly.

Did you have a look at this:?
http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/DxGetText

Comment: I understand that Lazarus use resourcestrings to make localization work. I don't find anything about simply use gettext code like _('Hello') function or TranslateComponent or automatic form translation.

Comment: I enhanced the answer with the resuls of a round of searching

Comment: I download the code from that link and get "gnugettext.pas(944,122) Error: Identifier not found "ResourceStringTableCount"" & "gnugettext.pas(951,63) Error: Identifier not found "GetResourceStringDefaultValue"

Comment: I could live with not automatic form traslation (my gui is minimal), but the lazarus DxGetText no compile at all, so i'm lost on this...

Comment: You need delphi mode obviously.

Answer (score 0):

[DKLang Localization Package](http://www.dk-soft.org/download.php?lang=en&cat_id=4) is an open source project that works very well.  It has not been tested under FreePascal, but we would be willing assist with any needed changes.

Comment: Well, I can test for sure, but looking at the page the dependency in TNT controls look like a problem. With the Delphi unicode support & compatibility with Freepascal, this is something to look at.

Comment: The TNT dependency is only on the pre D2009 version.

Comment: FPC can't yet run D2009+ code. While TUnicodestring exists, it is rudimentary.

Answer (score 0):

This one is note entirely free, but parts of it are: (The GUI editor isn't, but the code parts are, and the editor isn't strictly required):

http://www.be-precision.com/products/precision-langs/